# objects not aligned error

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7
And trying to get this code to work and keep receiving an error

```
nsample = 50
sig = 0.25
x1 = np.linspace(0,20, nsample)
X = np.c_[x1, np.sin(x1), (x1-5)**2, np.ones(nsample)]
beta = masterAverageList
y_true = np.dot(X, beta)
y = y_true + sig * np.random.normal(size=nsample)
```

However I keep getting objects are not aligned error
I think it has something to do with master average list being a list?

I forgot to mention the master array list has 196 items in it if it matters.  They are all floats

How can I correct this?

Thanks for any sugguestions

Comment: Can you please provide a short example for `masterAverageList` that produces the problem. Also, on what line is it raising an Exception, and what does the exception say?

Comment: You mean for the example what's in the list.     The master average list contains floats between 1.23697805 down to 1.0076944343, some other randoms would be 1.211134352, 1.023456895, 1.099897254.     And the exception looks like its for the line below.     Saying y_true = np.dot(X, beta).   ValueError: Objects are not aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on numpy broadcasting [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [here](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc). You are trying to take the dot product between two arrays which have incompatible shapes.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x1 = np.linspace(0,20,50)
>>> X = np.c_[x1,np.sin(x1),(x1-5)**2,np.ones(50)]
>>> beta = np.ones(196)
>>> y_true = np.dot(X,beta)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
>>> X.shape
(50, 4)
>>> beta.shape
(196,)
```

I'm not sure what to recommend, since I don't know what you were expecting by taking the dot product between these arrays.

Comment: After going through the suggested materials I have solved my problem thank you so much for a push in the correct direction

Comment: Would you happen to have some links on operates not broadcasting together with shape (2) (50). After some reading I didn't get much on how to fix it.  In the same code above its the last line of code.  And the previous is now                                                   .    y_true = ((X, beta))

Comment: @MysterMyster: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. If you have another question about broadcasting you should just create a new question.